# How to create RTSP-stream made from segments?

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, segment

I'm saving a live videostream to 10-second segments and then I'm going to translate them into RTSP stream.

Is it possible to create a local RTSP-stream which is made from several mp4 segments?
As I know, cvlc can solve such task, but I can't find any info about cvlc+segments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ffmpeg with concat demuxer.

Comment: @szatmary Thank you for your comment. But the main question is about the tool which allows me to make an RTSP server. I'll be appreciate if you could advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an rtsp server with `gst-rtsp-server`. (build the example `test-launch` )
Start the `./test-launch "gstsrc ! filter ! udpsink"` with a `gstreamer pipeline` that can manipulate your 10-second segments to h264 over udp or tcp.

You will probably need to be on a Linux OS & be familiar with assembling gstreamer's `gst-launch-1.0` pipelines in order to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I have an experience with video recording by gstreamer, but I digged into cvlc RTP streaming. As result, the streaming also works with GSTreamer, therefore I'll try to use it.